# Regular expression to match exact string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string variable

```
var str = ad2672a2361d10eacf8a05bd1b10d4d8linkedin or ad2672a2361d10eacf8a05bd1b10d4d8linkedinpage
```

I want a regular expression for exact match of linkedin in this string. i have managed to write a function to match linkedin in the string, but its taking both cases ie linkedin and linkedinpage. Please help me to find the regular expression to match linkedin only. Thanks

this is my code

```
if (/.*linkedin/.test(str)) {
    // found linkedin only 
}
```

Comment: Use: `/\blinkedin\b/.test(str);`

Comment: The term you're looking for is [word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

Comment: Do you need regex? You could just search the string for 'linkedin ' (with a space).

Comment: @AndyG Yes am looking for regular expression

Comment: All you need is to add `$` at the end of your regexp. It means "end of the line", so it will only match if "linkedin" is at the end and there are no more characters (except carriage return)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (/.*linkedin$/.test(str)) {
    // found linkedin only 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if (/.*linkedin$/.test(str)){
      //matches only linkedin, xxxxlinkedin,but not linkedinxxxx,xxxxlinkedinzzzz    
}
```

Comment: `// ...and obviously matches linkedinpage`

Comment: @malkam i only want to match ad2672a2361d10eacf8a05bd1b10d4d8linkedin not this one ad2672a2361d10eacf8a05bd1b10d4d8linkedinpage

Comment: Sorry I've over looked it .Then @Perry answer should work and I'm updating my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you only want word boundary to be applied after `linkedin`. You can just use:

```
/linkedin\b/.test(str);
```